# "technical work" singular or plural?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Should I use "are" or "is" in this sentence?

The technical work done at these meetings is an import precursor to the...

Comment: Yeah, "technical work" is just a variety of "work", a countable noun.  If there are more than one then it's "works".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use *is*.

The issue is that the "work" in "technical work" is a [mass noun or a noncount noun](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-mass-noun-1691370). Rather like "bread" or "advice," even when multiple items are involved the noun form would remain singular:

> I have received a lot of advice (but not "a lot of advices")
>
> I have eaten many loaves of bread (but not "loaves of breads")
>
> I have a ton of work to get done (but not "a ton of works")

So even if you are doing a lot of technical projects, you are in effect still doing *technical work*.

> The technical work ... is ...

Answer (score 1):

is

> The technical work done at these meetings is an import precursor to the ....

Subject here is "The technical work" and it's singular - so you have to use "is"